# Field and potential due to dipole

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

My TB gives the formulae for electric field and potential due to a dipole as:

$$|E| = \dfrac{k p}{r^3} \sqrt{1+ 3\cos^2θ}$$

$$|V| = \dfrac{k p}{r^2} \cosθ$$

Why are these expressions are not satisfying $E = \dfrac{-dV}{dr}$?

---

Edit: Is the following derivation correct?

Let a test charge be placed at origin and the dipole be at a distance x on the x-axis.

[image]
Equatorial field due to x component of dipole $E_x = \dfrac{2kp}{x^3} \cosθ$

Axial field due to y component of dipole $E_y = \dfrac{kp}{x^3} \sinθ$

If the particle is moved from origin to infinity (to the left) along x-axis, the potential drop will be only due to $E_x$:

$$|V| = \int^\infty_x E_x dx = \dfrac{kp \cosθ}{x^2} $$

And,
$$|E| = \sqrt{E_x ^ 2 + E_y ^ 2} =  \dfrac{k p}{x^3} \sqrt{1+ 3\cos^2θ}$$

Comment: Remember that $\mathbf E$ is a vector $(-dV/dx, -dV/dy)$ so $|E| = \sqrt{(-dV/dx)^2 + (-dV/dy)^2}$. It is not as simple as $|E| = d/dr(|V|)$.

Comment: Exactly. The formula you are expecting to find is valid for a spherically symmetric field, which the dipole field is not!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $\mathbf E$ is a vector to be calculated with the gradient
operator
$$\mathbf E=-\nabla V$$

If you want to do it in spherical coordinates ($r,\theta,\phi$),
then you need to use the [gradient operator in spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula).
Doing this calculation with the given dipole potential
$V=\frac{kp}{r^2}\cos\theta$,
you will find that $\mathbf E$ has components in
$r$ *and* $\theta$ direction (because $V$ depends on $r$ and $\theta$):
$$\begin{align}
E_r&=-\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}=\frac{2kp}{r^3}\cos\theta \\
E_\theta&=-\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial V}{\partial \theta}=\frac{kp}{r^3}\sin\theta
\end{align}$$

When you then calculate the magnitude of $\mathbf E$, you find
$$|\mathbf E|=\sqrt{E_r^2+E_\theta^2}
=\frac{kp}{r^3}\sqrt{1+3\cos^2\theta}$$
which is the formula from your textbook.

Comment: @Shub I thought your textbook would derive the dipole potential $V(r,\theta)$.
You can find a derivation also [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/dipole.html#c2).